# Random sobre un CSV en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Deseo obtener una *row* aleatoriamente de las 31 que contiene mi archivo CSV.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import csv 
import random 

path="/home/eocampo/Escritorio/porque_pregunta_6.csv" 
file=open(path,newline='') 
reader=csv.reader(file) 
data=[row for row in reader] 
reader = csv.reader(data[0], delimiter=',') 
i=0 
for row in reader: 
  print(row) 
  i=i+1 
  print(i)
```

Comment: Podrias agregar un poco mas de informacion a tu pregunta? Con solo 6 palabras es dificil saber que problema tenias es mente =)

Comment: import csv
import random
path="/home/eocampo/Escritorio/porque_pregunta_6.csv"
file=open(path,newline='')
reader=csv.reader(file)
data=[row for row in reader]
reader = csv.reader(data[0], delimiter=',')
i=0
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    i=i+1
print(i)

Comment: ese es mi codigo, ya tengo el list de mis csv, ahora lo que quiero es jalar solo una list aleatoriamente de esas 31 que tengo

Comment: [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) te elige al azar un elemento de una lista que le pases como parámetro. [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) te elige `k` elementos de una lista, también al azar (le pasas la lista y `k `)

Comment: @EdgarOcampo para futuras ocaciones, te recomendaria editar la pregunta para incluir informacion util, como la que me acabas de responder. Le da mas claridad a tu pregunta, y mas personas podran entender tu problema para resolverlo =)

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
# -- coding: utf-8 --
# -- coding: latin-1 --
import csv
import random

path="/home/eocampo/Escritorio/porque_pregunta_6.csv"
file=open(path,newline='')
reader=csv.reader(file)
data=[row for row in reader]
reader = csv.reader(data[0], delimiter=',')

randomList=[]
for row in reader:
    randomList.append(row)

newVar=random.choice(randomList)
print(newVar)

Comment: asi me quedo, mi logica era sobre el csv, pero no, cree una lista y sobre ese aplique el random.choice(newVar)

Comment: @EdgarOcampo El código en los comentarios queda completamente ilegible. Si se trata de código para aclarar algún detalle de la pregunta, puedes editar la pregunta y añadirlo allí. Si es una respuesta, puedes ponerla como tal (está permitido que te respondas a tus propias preguntas)

Answer (score 0):

Python no es mi fuerte, pero esto creo que te podria funcionar:

```
import csv 
import random

path="/home/eocampo/Escritorio/porque_pregunta_6.csv" 
file=open(path,newline='') 
reader=csv.reader(file) 
data=[row for row in reader] 
reader = csv.reader(data[0], delimiter=',') 

contador = 0
total_de_lineas = sum(1 for row in reader)
linea_random = random.randint(0, total_de_lineas)
for row in reader:
  if linea_random == contador
    print(row)
    break
  contador = contador + 1
```

Comment: Deja pruebo, se agradece tu ayuda bastante

Comment: Esto es muy ineficiente. Usa `random.choice()` para sacer un elemento, o `random.sample()` para sacar varios.

Comment: @abulafia podrias aclarar porque es ineficiente y como arreglarlo? Asi futuras personas que lean esta respuesta podran aprender algo (me incluyo) =)

Comment: @cavpollo Pues por ejemplo para contar el total de líneas usas un `sum()` sobre un montón de unos, en lugar de el operador `len()` sobre una lista. Para elegir una fila al azar eliges un número y después iteras sobre todas las filas hasta llegar a la que tiene ese número, en lugar de usar algo tipo `lista[linea_random]`. Además iteras dos veces sobre el `reader` (una para contar cuántas filas, otra para elegir una). Algunos iteradores sólo pueden ser usados una vez y después se "agotan" siendo necesario crearlos de nuevo.

Comment: @cavpollo Si crees que este tipo de análisis de código es interesante, podrías plantear esta respuesta tuya como una nueva pregunta del estilo "¿Por qué esto es ineficiente?" De este modo sería más visible y mi respuesta no quedaría perdida en un comentario...

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import random

path="/home/eocampo/Escritorio/porque_pregunta_6.csv"
file=open(path,newline='')
reader=csv.reader(file)
data=[row for row in reader]
reader = csv.reader(data[0], delimiter=',')

randomList=[]
for row in reader:
    randomList.append(row)

newVar=random.choice(randomList)
print(newVar)
```

Colegas, asi lo pude resolver, mi logica era iterar sobre el csv, pero no, cree una nueva lista cargando todo el csv y listo ya pude aplicar el choice

Comment: Gracias a uds dos que me ayudaron amigos

Comment: Un detalle, para construir la lista a partir del `reader` no necesitas ni el bucle. Puedes hacer `list(reader)`. Lo mismo para el `data=[row for row in reader]` que puede dejarse en `data=list(reader)`.

Comment: Hay una cosa que aún no entiendo, y es la segunda llamada a `csv.reader()` a la que estás pasando como fichero `data[0]`, que en realidad no es ningún fichero, sino la primera línea del `csv` que habías leido antes. ¿Te funciona eso? Yo diría que es un error.

Comment: si me funciona amigo, tienes razon, es a primera linea de mi CVS es una sola linea separada por comas

Comment: @abulafia agradezco tus comentarios y observaciones. Lo que hice es hacer respuestas aleatorias sobre un formulario de google con selenium y leyendo las respuestas desde el .csv... agradezco tu atencion